# Marbles program not removing

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I'm having some problems with a program I'm playing around with. I am trying to do this marble game where the player plays against the computer and remove marbles until the board is empty. My problem is that the class I have for removing the marbles doesn't seem to be removing it. I think it's something simple, but I just don't see it. The part where I THINK I'm having trouble with is in CAPITAL letters:

```
Pile tiles = new Pile();
tiles.createMarbles();
marbles = tiles.getMarbles();
System.out.println("There are now " + marbles + " left!");

HumanPlayer hum = new HumanPlayer();
SmartMode cpu = new SmartMode();
StupidMode badcpu = new StupidMode();

//ComputerMove cpu = new ComputerMove();
//PlayerMove hum = new PlayerMove();
do {
    if (compMove == true && marbles > 1) {
        if (compSmart) {
            //marbles = cpu.move(marbles);
            tiles.removesMarbles(cpu.move(marbles)); //THIS RIGHT HERE
            System.out.println("There are now " + marbles + " left!");
            compMove = false;
        }  if (!compSmart) {
            //marbles = badcpu.move(marbles);
            tiles.removesMarbles(badcpu.move(marbles)); // THIS RIGHT HERE
            System.out.println("There are now " + marbles + " left!");
            compMove = false;

        }
        /* marbles = (cpu.ComputerMove(marbles, compSmart));
         System.out.println("There are now " + marbles + " left!");
         compMove = false;*/
    } else if (compMove == false && marbles > 1) {
        //marbles = (hum.move(marbles));
        tiles.removesMarbles(hum.move(marbles)); // THIS RIGHT HERE
        System.out.println("There are now " + marbles + " left!");
        compMove = true;
    }

} while (marbles > 1);
```

The rest is not needed for answer

Comment: aside, you should not create a new instance of `Random` for every move, but rather for the `StupidMode` instance. Although it would not make a difference ;)

Comment: don't write `if (a) {} if (!a) {}`. use `else`: `if (a) {} else {}`

Comment: the condition `while (marbles > 1)` will not change, since `marbles` is not assigned within the loop.

Comment: What is it stupid code or stupid mode, etc?

Comment: StupidMode is a class that handles for when the person chooses the "easy" or "stupid" mode for the game, it removes marbles in a "stupid" way.

Comment: as rudolf said, update the value of marbel inside the do-while loop.

Comment: Yes, just did what rudolf said and it worked perfectly, thank you so much rudolf!!!!!!! :)

Comment: See @RudolfMühlbauer comment - use `while (tiles.getMarbles() > 1)`

Comment: While you may have your answer, it's really tough to get the context of your question without the *rest* of the code.  I would encourage you to avoid large edits that remove that degree of context, for future readers.

Comment: Fair enough, can at least the last two classes be removed? They are not needed for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the condition `while (marbles > 1)` will not change, since `marbles` is not assigned within the loop.

use:

```
while (tiles.getMarbles() > 1)
```

You use the construct:

```
do {
  if (... && marbles > 1 ) {}
  ...
} while(marbles > 1)
```

probably this does the same:

```
while (tiles.getMarbles() > 0 ) {
  // additional condition on marbles not required.
  if (...) {}
}
```

---

```
interface Movable {
   public int move();
}

class SmartPlayer implements Movable {
   public int move() {...}
}

Movable m = new SmartPlayer();
m.move();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rudolf! One more question, I want to call the `move()` method polymorphically. Right now I'm making objects to call it like `StupidMode badcpu = new StupidMode();` and then say `badcpu.move(argument)`, but I made an interface, so I was wondering how can I call that method through the interface so I don't have to make those objects and they don't have to depend on those classes. The interface is just has that one `move()` method.